# How to match the comma separated values in mysql and get the values

Tags: php, mysql

**My table** User

```
+----+-----------+---------+--------+---------+------+-------+
| id | name      | email   | number | call_no | chek | Extra |
+----+-----------+-------+----------+---------+------+-------+
|  1 | one       | a@a.com | 123    | 1164    |    1 | 1,2   |
+----+-----------+---------+---------+---------+------+------+
|  2 | two       | a@a.com | 123    | 1164    |    1 | 2,1   |
+----+-----------+---------+---------+---------+------+------+
```

I have the field called `Extra` it contains the value `1,2`

what is my question is ?

I need to match the 1,2 in the table id and myresult like `one,two` from the user table

For simple example query.what im tried is in below ?

```
select name from user Extra in('1,2');
```

My expected output is

**`one,two`**

If i tried to do in explode and if i run it in loop i can get the result but i need this in `sql` is it possible to get it?

Comment: Storing values as csv is very bad database design.

Comment: Change db design is an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a separate table with one row per `id` and each value of `extra`.  This is called a junction table.  SQL has a great data structure for storing lists of things, called a *table* not a *string*.  And, storing numbers as characters is even worse.

You can, however, do what you want with a `join` and aggregation:

```
select id, group_concat(e.name) as names
from table t left join
     table e
     on find_in_set(t.id, e.extra) > 0
group by t.id;
```

Comment: its working like a charm before i accept it i need one more clarification `names`  contains duplicate vallues how can i remove the duplicate value ?